# Captcha is really annoying - keeps loading forever

Tags: bug, captcha

I'm from a developing nation where Internet connection is of rather poor standards. But the captcha verification is of a poorer standard. I have a 32kBps connection.

```
PING stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=408 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=2 ttl=50 time=328 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=3 ttl=50 time=326 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=4 ttl=50 time=406 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=5 ttl=50 time=765 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=6 ttl=50 time=327 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=7 ttl=50 time=404 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=8 ttl=50 time=403 ms
^C
--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 8 received, 11% packet loss, time 8004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 326.775/421.256/765.219/134.911 ms

PING google.com (74.125.236.169) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.169): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=141 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.169): icmp_req=2 ttl=53 time=139 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.169): icmp_req=3 ttl=53 time=148 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.169): icmp_req=4 ttl=53 time=115 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.169): icmp_req=5 ttl=53 time=193 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.169): icmp_req=6 ttl=53 time=192 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 115.375/155.057/193.696/28.626 ms

PING recaptcha.net (74.125.236.168) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.236.168): icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=206 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.236.168): icmp_req=2 ttl=54 time=207 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.236.168): icmp_req=3 ttl=54 time=204 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.236.168): icmp_req=4 ttl=54 time=203 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.236.168): icmp_req=5 ttl=54 time=131 ms
^C
--- recaptcha.net ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 131.648/190.787/207.442/29.612 ms
```

The connection is pretty okay I guess. Yet when I click on the really impressive "I'm a human being" button, it keeps loading forever. I have checked with firefox and chromium and I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Any chance that this will get fixed?

Edit : seems like it will work if I press on the reload button of the captcha and type in the new one. Weird!

Comment: This sounds like a problem with ReCAPTCHA rather than SO, doesn't it? Can you try another site that uses the service to see whether they have the same problem?

Comment: @Pekka good idea